# Mime type for all kind of image formats

Tags: javascript, image, video, mime-types

Is there any specific type of mimetype for images , which accecpts all sort of images not videos if so please help me here

i have to differenciate images and videos while uploading so am testing like this

```
    if(req.body.type == 'img' || req.file.mimetype != 'image/jpeg'){
    // 
    }else if(req.body.type == 'video' || req.file.mimetype != 'video/mp4'){
    // 
    }else{
}
```

if type is img then it should perform some certain set of things if the type is video the it has to process some other features

the above code is working fine if the type is img and upload image/jpeg formats or if the type is video for video/mp4 formats files but it will make mess if i upload any mp3, gif,png files it will be redirected to last else condition even they are belongs to videos and images family is is there any mime-type instead of video/mp4 or image/jpeg which supports all format images and all format videos

Comment: How about `req.file.mimetype.startWith( 'image/' )` and `req.file.mimetype.startsWith( 'video/' )` instead of full mime checks? Also, mp3 doesn;'t match either, so you might want to do `|| req.file.mimetype.startsWith( 'audio/' )` or something (not sure what the mime type of mp3 is). All `image` types start with `image/` as far as I know, and the same is true for video.

Comment: @somethinghere yes thank you this works for my problem!! and you are right mime type for mp3 is `audio/` ;)